# Losing css resources with new spring mvc while using nginx

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, nginx

We upgraded spring boot version from 1.4.6. to 2.0.6. which made us lose some icons on UI. Our application has resource caching enabled via spring. While digging I figured that part of the caching logic is done by transformers, so I found that behaviour of  [CssLinkResourceTransformer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/CssLinkResourceTransformer.html) was changed by [SPR-14597](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/1199/commits/679b661e199502fc47f47917dd9a54aea98529b2) so that instead of relative, absolute paths to resources are provided.

This messed us up a bit because links to our resources became wrong. We are using nginx as proxy to our to applications, our nginx config is something similar to this:

```
http {
  ....
  server { 
    server_name my_host;
    ...

    location / {
        return 302 $scheme://$http_host/application1/;
    }

    location /application1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
    }
    location /application2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002/;
    }
}
```

This means that all requests coming to `http://my_host/application1` will be forwareded to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/` where one of our applications resides, same logic with application2

We have a style css that is pointing to our resource, so now instead of `url(fontawesome-webfont-1234.eot)` reference in style.css we got `url(/fontawesome-webfont-1234.eot)` because CssLinkResource resolver puts our context path to get absolute path. This would be fine if we had not be hiding behind nginx, but now my browser is trying to fetch the resource by calling `http://my_host/fontawesome-webfont-1234.eot` instead of `http://my_host/application1/fontawesome-webfont-1234.eot`

We solved this issue by changing the nginx configuration so that proxy pass url also contains location url in it, and we updated our spring boot application.yml configuration context path

```
http {
  ....
  server { 
    server_name my_host;
    ...

    location / {
        return 302 $scheme://$http_host/application1/;
    }

    location /application1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/application1;
    }
    location /application2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002/application2;
    }
}
```

Spring boot application.yml:

```
...
server:
  address: 0.0.0.0
  port: 8001
  servlet:
      context-path: /application1
...
```

Is this really the way how to do it or am I missing something? I am not happy with the way how my nginx configuration looks like now, it is obvious that what I added to proxy_pass url seems redundant